# MySQL failing to establish a connection using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, connection

Using ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on Lenovo t410. 
Using apache2 and Mysql 5.5 and attempting to connect via localhost

I am attempting to establish a connection to a database that I made on localhost. When the line of code is reached to establish a connection, it seems Mysql simply hangs, and there is no error message displayed after. I verified that an echo works immediately prior to the connection attempt. I know that apache2 server is working as I can access the index page and display my html form.

I have tried etc/mysql/my.cnf  setting the bind address to localhost.

My line of code looks like:

```
// Attempts to establish connection to MySql server
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

// Prints error message if the connection to MySql fails
if (!$connection){
    die("Connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

echo "Connection established.";
```

I tried the connection line with single quotes and with no semi-colon as well.

I am willing to post the contents of any configuration file I have if the error isn't syntax. I haven't done anything fancy to Ubuntu, everything is the default install. I am new to CS and especially databases, PHP, and networking. This is my little experiment that I am stuck on.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks,

- Don

Comment: Have you established whether mysql is running as service?

Comment: What happens if you add this to the beginning of your code: `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`?

Comment: Per PHP official doc, you should consider using MySQLi and mysqli_connect instead of mysql_connect. See php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php and php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php.

Comment: @jexact When I add: error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);    I didn't notice anything at first. To make sure my code was making it past this point I inserted an echo statement after that line but before establishing a connection. My echo statement printed, and the connection hung again. Was there something in particular you would expect me to see?

Comment: @jexact I added this line of code: ini_set('display_errors', 1); and finally got the error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/index.php on line 9 . I am unsure what this means though

Answer (score 1):

Can it be, because there is no error message, that the connection IS established, but you didn't do anything with it?
I mean, what is the rest of your code, is there after your code here something like:

```
mysql_select_db("database_name",$connection);
```

Comment: Yes my code does have that line of code as well. I would post but I cannot seem to get my code in the format that I did in my original post. My guess would be that the connection established echo would hit if the connection was created.

Comment: Your comment: "I added this line of code: ini_set('display_errors', 1); and finally got the error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/index.php on line 9 . I am unsure what this means though"----- 
This indicates that the function is not available. Probably mysql is not running as service. You have to check your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your last comment, it appears the mysql extensions are not being loaded. Have a look at your `php.ini`, uncomment the following line (remove the semicolon at the beginning of the line) and restart your apache:

```
extension=php_mysql.so
```

Make sure the extension exists in the php extensions directory.

Due to the fact that you are using MySQL version > 4.1.3 it is strongly recommended that you use the mysqli extension instead. Have a look at this: [PHP: MySQL Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)

Answer (score -1):

try to set

```
$mysql_user = "your_username";
$mysql_pass = "your_password";
$mysql_server = "Servername";

$link = mysql_connect($mysql_server,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass);
if (!$link) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500');
    exit();
```

Comment: How is that going to help? If anything, you're giving LESS information about the failure than the original code!

Comment: @user1506616 I inserted this code and added the closing angle bracket etc. for a controlled test and it appears that the 'if' statement is not reached.